# Changing one 'attribute' of a href depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, resize, responsive-design

Dear stackoverflowers,

I'm trying to change the 'data-placement' attribute in my href, depending on the screensize. Somehow I cannot get it to work. The desired goal is to change the 'data-placement' attribute from 'left' to 'right'.

That's the link with the attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="changedataplacement" data-placement="left">
```

This is the javascript which doesn't appear to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $window = $(window);

function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 979) {
        $('#changedataplacement').Attr('data-placement','right');
    }  
    else {  
        $('#changedataplacement').Attr('data-placement','left'); 
    } 
}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Anyone with a good idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace `Attr` with `attr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `.attr()` function name should be lowercase. JavaScript is case sensitive!
You should use a debug console in order for these errors to popup!

Comment: Yeah I checked it out on JSFiddle. The capital "A" was the only error.